Attempting to delete a contact gives 'The contact might be the Membership Organization of a Membership Type.'
The contact was an individual, not an organisation. Examining the code in /vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/Delete.php and /vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php showed that this message could be triggered by the user having an associated Drupal account. This proved to be the case - deleting their account allowed their Contact record to be deleted. Is there a case for updating the code so the error messages are more meaningful?

never seen this. can you pls confirm what CMS you are using

I just tried to replicate on 5.70.x via the following (drupal) - create new contact - add CMS user - delete new contact - no such msg. can you confirm if what you are doing is replicable and if so, what steps to take

It might not be in 5.70. It might be due to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29026. But the message has been updated in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30053 in 5.74.

We saw it in 5.72.1 under Drupal. CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::deleteContact returns TRUE if successful and FALSE if not. One reason for failure is that it finds a ufMatch to the CMS. However, /vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/Delete.php currently just gives the above message on FALSE, PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30053 does a ufMatch test and gives a sensible message if it finds one.

Problem is likely to be that older civicrm gave an unhelpful incorrect warning when the issue was actually trying to delete a Contact that still had a connection to a CMS User
